# -[GKPlayerInternal setAuthenticateHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, ios5, gamekit, sigabrt

Get error SIGABRT with this log:
"-[GKPlayerInternal setAuthenticateHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

I test this on iPad 3 iOS 5.1.1

```
GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)  //error here
{ /* some code */ };
```

On iOS 6 this work fine

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad you mentioned you're trying this with iOS 5.

According to Apple's documentation, ["`authenticateHandler`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKLocalPlayer/authenticateHandler) is iOS 6 and newer ***only***.